# form validation case in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to validate below form. but required validation message did not appear. but my other textbox validation worked well. this in input type="file". how i validate it as a required field. please check below sample.

```html
<form name="form" #f="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && save();">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 pt-3">
        <label>Upload CV</label>
        <input type="file" required [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':f.touched && cvFile.invalid}" name="userCv" #cvFile="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="signupModel.cvFile" (change)="selectCvFile($event)" />
    <div *ngIf="cvFile.invalid && f.touched" class="invalid-feedback">
        <div *ngIf="cvFile.errors.required">Cv is required</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit"> Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function recurses through controls in a form group and gently touches them and we can use `cvFile.touched && cvFile.invalid` condition to display the error messages.

```
 /**
   * Marks all controls in a form group as touched
   * @param formGroup - The form group to touch
   */
  private markAsTouched(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    (<any>Object).values(formGroup.controls).forEach(control => {
      control.markAsTouched();

      if (control.controls) {
        this.markAsTouched(control);
      }
    });
  }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mfjg5p)